# Is this a job for joins

Tags: mysql, join

Simply looking for a better direction, not a solution.

I have two tables - A, B

Table A has ip address and time (time will be either equal to or between starttime and endtime)

Table B has username, starttime, endtime, ip address

The job, I am trying to find out what ip address and time in in table A correspond the username in table B.

More generally, who (username) was using a specific ip address at a specific time.

Assuming my explanation makes sense, does this seem like something using joins can accomplish between the two tables? If not what is the next best step. I am trying to avoid a lot of manual queries from one table to another.

Any direction is welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a join is appropriate.  The condition needs to be a compound condition that matches both the ip address and the time constraints.

```
select B.username, A.ipaddress, A.time
 from A inner join B on A.ipaddress = B.ipaddress 
                        and A.time between B.starttime and B.endtime
```

Comment: That was what I was wondering. With those examples I think you just saved me 8 hours. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Yes - that's exactly the kind of situation you should use a JOIN in.

```
    SELECT x, y, z
      FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.ip_address = b.ip_address
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
WHERE a.ip_address = b.ip_address 
    AND b.starttime <= a.time 
    AND a.time <= b.endtime
```